# No such file or directory: how can I resolve this?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, process

while I was trying to make a login system, I got this error:
**Impossibile interrogare il database No such file or directory**

The PHP process code is this:

```
<?php    
session_start();

include('db-conn-dashboard.php');

$nomeutente = $_POST['nomeutente'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$nomeutente = stripcslashes($nomeutente);
$password = stripcslashes($password);
$nomeutente = mysql_real_escape_string($nomeutente);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profili WHERE nomeutente = '$nomeutente' and password = '$password'")
    or die("Impossibile interrogare il database ".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row['nomeutente'] == $nomeutente && $row['password'] == $password){
    $_SESSION['login_user1'] = "autorizzato1";
    $_SESSION['autorizzato'] = 1;
    header('location: ../pages/home.php');
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Nome utente o password errati. Riprova.")
    window.location= "../pages/login.php"</script>';
}
?>
```

**And the form is this:**

```
<form role="form" action="../php/processo-accesso.php" method="POST">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf007;  Nome utente" name="nomeutente" type="text" style="font-family: fontawesome, arial;" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf084;  Password" style="font-family: fontawesome, arial;" name="password" type="password" required>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="accedi" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accedi" style="width: 100%;">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Comment: 1) `mysql_*` functions were *deprecated* in php5 and *removed* in php7. Use Mysqli or PDO. 2) you're open to SQL injection. 3) it's bad practice to mix JS and php - consider using AJAX if need be.

Comment: also, what's your file tree looking like? I wager that db-conn-dashboard.php isn't in the same directory as the processo-accesso script

Comment: Use absolute pathes with includes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profili WHERE nomeutente = '$nomeutente' and password = '$password'")
    or die("Impossibile interrogare il database ".mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```